# Asp.net autocomplete Extender not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, autocompleteextender

I want to make textbox autocomplete with database. I used following code but in output extender shows html codes. It is not even executing code behind functions. Following code I have used which is not working properly.

[image]

ASPx page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="CS.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" 
EnablePageMethods = "true">
</asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtContactsSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="SearchCustomers" 
    MinimumPrefixLength="2"
    CompletionInterval="100" EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="10" 
    TargetControlID="txtContactsSearch"
    ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" FirstRowSelected = "false">
</cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

C# Code

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<string> SearchCustomers(string prefixText, int count)
{
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection())
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager
                .ConnectionStrings["conio"].ConnectionString;
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select clientID from clientsDetails where "  +
            "clientID like @SearchText + '%'";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText);
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            List<string> customers = new List<string>();
            using (MySqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    customers.Add(sdr["clientID"].ToString());
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
            return customers;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you have registered `AjaxControlToolkit` and add `ScriptManager `

Comment: @Div Yes that is already added.

Comment: Please add to the question!

Comment: refer [this link](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/201099/autocomplete-with-database-and-ajaxcontroltoolkit)

Comment: @Div I have updated in question

Comment: @RahulHendawe: OP has refer from [this](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/AJAX-AutoCompleteExtender-Example-in-ASPNet.aspx)

Comment: @RahulHendawe If you can tell me what's wrong with this code. Because this is also working code & downloaded from aspsnippets.

Comment: @SUN Do you have any `routes` in use in the application?

Comment: @user1429080 Yes I have routes

Answer (score 1):

You are viewing the page that contains the `TextBox` on the URL:

> http://localhost:64890/CS

This seems to be mapped by a `route` to the page

> CS.aspx

When the `AutoCompleteExtender` sends it's `AJAX` request, it will send it to this address:

> http://localhost:64890/CS/SearchCustomers

This is likely picked up by some `route` that you have set up, and the result is that it does not go to the `PageMethod` in `CS.aspx.cs` but is instead handled in some other way.

Assuming your `CS.aspx` page in in the web application root folder, you may be able to fix it by adding this:

```
ServicePath="~/CS.aspx"
```

to you `AutoCompleteExtender`. Like so:

```
<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="SearchCustomers"
    MinimumPrefixLength="2"
    ServicePath="~/CS.aspx"
    CompletionInterval="100" EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="10"
    TargetControlID="txtContactsSearch"
    ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" FirstRowSelected="false">
</cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Comment: No man. I set properties in extender like you shown but now no output is showing.. I also tried same codes in simple web form by creating new project & it worked fine. In my actual project I routes.

Comment: @SUN What is the path to `CS.aspx` within your solution/web application. And also, can you add your routes to the question?

Comment: My page name is auto.aspx so  my servicepath is ~/auto.apsx

Answer (score 0):

```
    add  <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager></cc1:ToolkitScriptManager> instead of   <asp:ScriptManager></asp:ScriptManager>

your aspx page  ----

    <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" 
    EnablePageMethods = "true">
    </cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtContactsSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
               <cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="SearchCustomers" MinimumPrefixLength="1" CompletionInterval="10"  
                EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="10" TargetControlID="txtContactsSearch" ID="AutoCompleteExtender2"  
                runat="server" FirstRowSelected="false"></cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>  


    your cs page----

    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
            [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
            public static List<string> SearchCustomers(string prefixText, int count)
            {

                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
                {
                    conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager
                            .ConnectionStrings["conio"].ConnectionString;
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = "select clientID from clientsDetails where "+"clientID like @SearchText + '%'";
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText);
                        cmd.Connection = conn;
                        conn.Open();
                        List<string> customers = new List<string>();
                        using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (sdr.Read())
                            {
                                customers.Add(sdr["name"].ToString());
                            }
                        }
                        conn.Close();
                        return customers;
                    }
                }
            }
```